# How to use pg_checksums in docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm running a PostgreSQL server on docker and I'm trying to set pg_checksums for validity check.

However for doing that the server should be in shut-down state, but the docker container itself has been shut-downed if I try to stop the postgres server.
Yes, it is a natural result as docker container itself is the process.

So then, how can I use `pg_checksums` on docker container? Is it unavailable upon containers?

Comment: You can have to run it in the container. Stop the container and run in on the volume.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Can I run it on the volume without container? Sorry I don't have much a knowledge about docker.

Comment: Nor do I. But isn't it just a directory?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes, but the containers and volumes are on production server and I don't have rights to install postgres command line tools directly on the server. The postgres command line tools like pg_checksums are only available on docker containers now.

Comment: Create another container with the same volume and `pg_checksums` as executable. Aside: containers certainly make administration more complicated.